Opera closes when I pressed ALT key on ubuntu
When I press the ALT key Opera closes on ubuntu. What is the problem?
➜  ~ opera

(opera:25045): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:59:18.901: GTK+ module /snap/opera/313/gnome-platform/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so cannot be loaded.
GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported.
Gtk-Message: 22:59:18.901: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

(opera:25045): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:59:18.902: GTK+ module /snap/opera/313/gnome-platform/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so cannot be loaded.
GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported.
Gtk-Message: 22:59:18.902: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
/usr/share/libdrm/amdgpu.ids: No such file or directory
➜  ~ 

